# Are "fpqc algebraic spaces" algebraic spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces

> Suppose $F:Sch^\text{op}\to Set$ is a sheaf in the fpqc topology, has quasi-compact representable diagonal, and has an fpqc cover by a scheme. Must $F$ be an algebraic space? That is, must $F$ have an étale cover by a scheme?

Note that it is enough to find an fppf cover of $F$ by a scheme, at which point you know that $F$ is an algebraic stack ("Artin's slice theorem", 10.1 of Laumon-Moret-Bailly) fibered in sets, [so it's an algebraic space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41833/is-every-artin-dm-algebraic-stack-fibered-in-sets-an-algebraic-space/41834#41834).

The analogous question, "is every fpqc stack an algebraic stack?" has a [negative answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15082/fpqc-covers-of-stacks), but the counterexample is "purely stacky".

Comment: A. J. de Jong has a post about this: http://math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=1927

Comment: To clarify, by an "fpqc cover", I meant a morphism which is representable by fpqc morphisms of schemes, which is the case de Jong's example focuses on.